# How to reduce this regex to fit in Lua?

Tags: regex, lua

I'm trying to do a regex that captures the longest string before a possibly ending letter "c", in Lua.

For example,

- Given `abc`, match `ab`
- Given `acc`, match `ac`
- Given `abcd`, match `abcd`
- Given `abd`, match `abd`

The solution I came up is `^(.+(?=c$)|.+(?!c$))`. However, Lua does not have lookahead, so I'm thinking if there is a way to reduce this to something that Lua natively supports.

Comment: Can you use a group of the match? Or, knowing the last char is “c”, programmatically remove the last char of the match before use?

Comment: `s:match("(.-)c?$")`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff answer is neat and seems to fulfill OP's requirements. Might put in a dedicated answer.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I think the smart use of Lua-exclusive `-` here is the way to go. Answers below are either wrong or too complicated.

Comment: @CrendKing - `.-` is not Lua-exclusive.  The same can be written as `.*?` in regex.  Lua has it just one symbol shorter :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff. TIL something not only useful for Lua but regex in general. Thanks. So you making a dedicated answer or not? If not, I'll do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Egor Skriptunoff provided the best answer in my opinion [in the comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584168/how-to-reduce-this-regex-to-fit-in-lua/68584893?noredirect=1#comment121213444_68584168). Since he didn't leave it as dedicated answer, I'll close this question for him. I do not hold any credit.

Original answer:

```
s:match("(.-)c?$")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(string.match(str:reverse(), "^c(.+)") or str:reverse()):reverse()`. If nothing is matched, then the original string is returned.

[Updated to fix the logic]

Comment: From my tests, it does not fulfill OP requirements, with `abc` it returns `abc` instead of `ab` and with `abcd` it returns `abc` instead of `abcd`.

Comment: If "c" appears in the middle, it should be included just as everything else. It's just when the optional "c" appears at the end that I want to specially handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"s:match("([^c]+c?[^c]*)c$") or s`, this will get all non-`c` characters then potentially a `c` followed by any remaining non-`c` characters and the final c if present, in the event of no match it returns the whole string.

Here is an example:

```lua
strs = {
  "abc",
  "acc",
  "abd",
  "abcd",
}

for _,s in ipairs(strs) do
  print(s, s:match("([^c]+c?[^c]*)c$") or s)
end
```

Output:

```
abc    ab
acc    ac 
abd    abd
abcd   abcd
```

Comment: Output in my test for "abcd" is `ab`.

Comment: corrected forgot the `$` to mark the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use a capture group to capture 1 more occurrences of any char except `c` followed by optional `c` chars.

Then match a `c` char at the end of the string outside of the group.

```
([^c]+c*)c$
```

The pattern matches

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^c]+c*` Match 1+ times any char except `c` followed by matching optional `c` chars
- `)` Close group 1
- `c$` Match a `c` chat at the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QgsJBX/1)

In the code, you can print the value of group 1 if it exists, else print the whole string if there is not match.

I have no experience in Lua, but looking at the code (and borrowing it for an example) posted by [@Nifim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7396148/nifim) this would match:

```
strs = {
  "abc",
  "acc",
  "abd",
  "abcd",
  "c"
}

for _,s in ipairs(strs) do
  print(s:match("([^c]+c*)c$") or s)
end
```

Output

```
ab
ac
abd
abcd
c
```